# Getting ip address into my own code... (cordova - cordova-plugin-networkinterface)

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm having a lot of troubles, trying to get the ip adress into a variable, in javascript.
This function, here, work correctly: it gives me an alert, with the correct ip address.

```
networkinterface.getIPAddress(function (ip) { alert(ip); });
```

But when i try to get this ip in order to get it in my own code (myip), I can't seem to get it working :

```
myip = networkinterface.getIPAddress(function (ip) { return ip;} );
```

What am i doing wrong, here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All plugin things in cordova are event driven. That means, that you can't set a variable like you do.

What you have to do is to write it this way:

```
networkinterface.getIPAddress(function (ip) {
    // Your logic here
}
```

What you also can do is, to use some triggers.

Comment: ok ... thanks for the info, i didn't know it wasn't possible. It will become complicated if i need to use a lot of plugins, using each other data.. I will look into triggers, then. Thanks !

Comment: Thx for accepting. If you use a lot of triggers, then it is going complicated. A good way is to separate the app in small functions where you integrate your own callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

My code can work like this:

```
$window.networkinterface.getIPAddress(function (ip) { alert(ip); });
```

Comment: Firstly,to include the Network Interface plugin in your PhoneGap Build application, add this to your config.xml:

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-networkinterface" source="npm" />